# Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: javascript, html

Intento mostrar un **pdf** en un **popup** y este me arroja el siguiente error en consola:

> Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```js
let elemento = $('<iframe/>',{
class:'doc',
embedded:'true',
width:'100%',
height:'480',
src:'https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/2d70889b-1eb0-4496-bee7-bee2f67af70c-8535a2c4-89c6-4b3c-910a-3683a6c98e2c.pdf',
});
elemento.appendTo($('#pdf'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='pdf'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [documentación de la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) es clara al respecto:

> El encabezado de respuesta HTTP `X-Frame-Options` puede ser usado para indicar si debería permitírsele a un navegador renderizar una página en un `<frame>`, `<iframe>` o `<object>`.
>   
>   La seguridad añadida sólo es proporcionada si el usuario que está accediendo al documento está utilizando un navegador que soporte X-Frame-Options.

Así que tienes pocas opciones:

- Si el servidor está bajo tu control, puedes eliminar dicha cabecera o establecerle un valor mas de tu conveniencia:

> #### DENY
>
> La página no puede ser mostrada en un marco, independiente del sitio que esté intentándolo.
>
> #### SAMEORIGIN
>
> La página sólo puede ser mostrada en un marco del mismo origen que dicha página.
>
> #### ALLOW-FROM uri
>
> La página sólo puede ser mostrada en un marco del origen especificado.

- Si el servidor no está bajo tu control, y el navegador admite configurar su respuesta ante una cabecera `X-Frame-Options`, pues mas o menos lo mismo: configurarlo según necesites. Esto es dependiente de cada navegador (pueden existir *plugins* que te ayuden en esto).
- Si tu navegador no soporta configurar su respuesta, ni existe ningún *plugin* pare el mismo que te solucione el problema ... pues cambiar de navegador :-)